# Routes to sub-directory won't work (but work in root /views)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It's been frustrating, since it's so basic but.... Routing works, but not to a subdirectory. Using MAMP.

The target file is in: views/foo/bar

`Route::get('bar', function(){
    return View::make('foo.bar'); });  // works, the view renders`

`Route::get('foo/bar', function()
    return View::make('foo.bar');  // doesn't work`

Causes? Solution? Thanks for assisting, I realize it's probably something that'll make me slap my forehead.

Comment: Can you access it with `localhost/yoursite/index.php/foo/bar`? If so, make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change '/' to '.':

```
Route::get('foo.bar', function() return View::make('foo.bar');
```

Comment: get expects a url, I don't believe dot-notation works there (not on my system at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

This route (your second example) works for me (tested) and it is a valid Laravel route:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', function(){ return View::make('foo.bar'); });
```

It returns the view file views/foo/bar.blade.php.

It doesn't really has something todo with a "subdirectory". You just define the URL part. So this one works too:

```
Route::get('this/is/also/a/route/to/foo/bar', function(){ return View::make('foo.bar'); });
```

Make sure you put the "return View" stuff in curly brackets (like you've did in your first route).

Check if your MAMP installation works.